# Cannot get rsync to keep source file ownership, tried many tricks

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to rsync some directories from a webserver running RHEL5 to a system running Xubuntu. I have rsync, ssh, and keys setup for the machines. I've tried everything so that when i backup from the source, the destination maintains the user and group names,etc.

Source:

> ```
> drwx--x--x  8 root     root     4096 Feb  8 03:29 ./
> drwxr-xr-x 29 root     root     4096 Feb  6 14:46 ../
> drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root     4096 Dec 19 14:58 .cpan/
> drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 Feb  8 03:29 .cpanm/
> drwx------  6 root     root     4096 Feb  7 03:29 .cpcpan/
> drwx------  4 root     root     4096 Aug 16  2010 cpeasyapache/
> drwx--x--x 35 foreve24 foreve24 4096 Feb  6 11:33 foreve24/
> drwx------  2 root     root     4096 Mar  8  2011 MySQL-install/
> ```

Destination:

> ```
> drwx--x--x 8 root    root    4096 Feb  8 03:29 .
> drwxr-xr-x 7 sbackup sbackup 4096 Feb  8 12:25 ..
> drwxr-xr-x 5 root    root    4096 Feb  8 12:25 .cpan
> drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root    4096 Feb  8 12:25 .cpanm
> drwx------ 6 root    root    4096 Feb  8 12:25 .cpcpan
> drwx------ 4 root    root    4096 Feb  8 12:25 cpeasyapache
> drwx------ 2 root    root    4096 Feb  8 12:25 foreve24
> drwx------ 2 root    root    4096 Mar  8  2011 MySQL-install
> ```

As you can see everything is kept as root. Here's my insane rsync command i'm using:

```
sudo /usr/bin/rsync --rsync-path="sudo /usr/bin/rsync" -azvrpogRHAX --fake-super --numeric-ids --rsh='ssh -l root -p 14308' --files-from=/home/foreve24/backup_files/movelist / rsync://root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/sitebackup/
```

I started with:

```
rsync -azvrR --rsh='sudo ssh -p 14308' --files-from=/home/foreve24/backup_files/movelist / rsync://sbackup@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/sitebackup
```

This has about every suggestion i've seen but I still can't get 'foreve24' as user and group for example.

The xubuntu server is using rsyncd i believe; is there configuration or do i have to disable to that in order to properly copy permissions?

Is /etc/passwd containing the same users the only way? if so, how do i properly deal with already assigned and conflicting UID and GID in the passwd files?

I have a file/script method to re-replicate the permissions but my understanding is I can get rsync to preserve them somehow in this instance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First, an easy question: Does foreve24:foreve24 exist on the destination system?